# Changing domain to another server

Tags: server, dns, web-hosting, host

In the past, the domain was hired and used on a physical server (which still exists today)
And now I need this domain to stop directing the old physical server and start redirecting to the new one (which will also be physical)

**Old Server** : Linux Apache

**New Server** : Windows (IIS?, Apache?, WAMP? is still being decided)

Can someone give me a tip? I'm in the dark here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is find the nameserver addresses available on your new hosting account.

The quickest way to find your new hosting account's nameservers is to look at the information in the email your hosting service sent you the first time you purchased hosting, or from the documentation provided by your hosting service's website. If you're still confused about where to get one, contact your hosting provider and ask them for a “DNS server” or “name server” for your domain.

Nameservers are usually in the form of *ns1.companyname.com*, *ns2.companyname.com*, etc., where companyname.com is usually the name/brand of your hosting service.

Your hosting service will generally provide 2 or more nameservers that you can use. Write down all the nameservers. It would be even better if you save the email/web page that contains the nameserver info so that later you can copy and paste it directly. Later in the next step, you must enter this nameserver information into the control panel where you purchased the domain (registrar), exactly as stated.

After you get the nameserver information, go to the domain control panel at your registrar. Don't forget, this means you're logging into the system where you bought the domain and going to where the domain management section is.

Once you find the appropriate page to change your nameservers, you will usually see a form that will allow you to enter Nameserver #1 (or “Primary Name Server”), Nameserver #2 (or “Secondary Name Server”), and maybe a few others (such as the 3rd and 4th nameservers). The terms may not always be the same, but the basic meaning will still be your first nameserver, 2nd and so on.

Fill in your nameservers, usually starting with ns1, into the **Nameserver #1** field. After that type your 2nd name server, usually the name starts with ns2, to **Nameserver #2**, and so on. A domain name has at least 2 name servers associated with it. Some web hosting services provide more than 2, some only 2.

After the nameservers are installed with details, done. You only need to wait a moment until your website can be accessed using your domain name. Usually, it only takes a few hours for the machine to work properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to log into your Registrar account and update your DNS to point the domain to the public IP address of the new server.

This is normally a fairly easy and quick change. As an example, you can check out how to make DNS updates on [GoDaddy here](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manage-dns-records-680).

Depending on which new server you chose and the server provider, there may be additional steps involved in order for the new server to receive external traffic. Additional steps may include, but not limited to, updating a firewall and configuring the server settings.